# Best of CommunityBuilding

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This is a place to collect CommunityBuilding success stories!

Did CommunityBuilding help you solve some real problems you faced in the context of your own online or real-world community? Are there some questions & answers that led to significant improvements and achievements for your community? Any ideas developed on this site that have been useful for your own community? Then add your story in an answer! (One story per answer, please!)

Disclaimer: the idea for this thread has been [taken](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617) from MathOverflow.

Comment: Since Community Building itself isn't really considered a science or a skill yet, I don't know how to feel about this. It's nice to cover some of the success stories, nonetheless, it doesn't help the community itself, does it? The idea feels more like a bigger way to express "Thank you!". Often we can't realize what the impact of the stories were or are because privacy is an important aspect here. The barrier of the internet doesn't let me feel a real impact of our actions, hence I'm unsure about this. Can somebody explain to me more in depth how this idea can help us, please?

Comment: @Zerotime it can help with promoting the site by documenting (some of) its successes and usefulness as well as increase the nice community feeling and spirit on CommunityBuilding. To me it seems both aspects are helpful for our community.

Comment: Can we really document successes? I don't think that we will be thanked externally in any way as privacy is important here. I can agree to the nice feeling, however, I still believe that it just is a bigger way to express gratitude.

Answer (score 8):

Taking serious the good advice Andy has given to me in [this](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1242/437) answer to my question about how to get an announcement of our community in a professional journal, I successfully approached the editor in chief per email.

As a result, I had a very nice telephone conversation with this editor about our community. A summary of our discussion will be printed in the form of an interview in this month's issue of the national professional journal about our site topic.

Comment: Awesome. If that interview is available online when it's published I'd be interested in reading it too.